# LEFT JOIN no retorna valores NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo dos tablas:

**AppWindowsEvent:**

```
CREATE TABLE [AppWindowsEvent]
(
[idAppWindowEvent]      INT IDENTITY(1,1)
, [idAppWindow]         INT
, [idMill]              INT
, [idEventType]         INT
, [Order]               INT
, CONSTRAINT PK_idAppWindowEvent PRIMARY KEY ([idAppWindowEvent])
, CONSTRAINT FK_idAppWindowEvent_AppWindow FOREIGN KEY ([idAppWindow]) REFERENCES [AppWindow]([idAppWindow])
, CONSTRAINT FK_idAppWindowEvent_EventType FOREIGN KEY ([idEventType]) REFERENCES [EventType]([idEventType])
)
```

**Event:**

```
CREATE TABLE [Event]       
(
[idEvent] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
, [idEventType] [INT] NOT NULL
, [idEntity] [INT] NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT PK_IdEvent PRIMARY KEY([idEvent])
, CONSTRAINT [FK_Event_EventType] FOREIGN KEY([idEventType]) REFERENCES [EventType] ([idEventType])
)
```

**EL PROBLEMA:**
En la tabla tengo conjuntos de Eventos para ciertos filtros (`idAppWindow` y `idMill`), para cada combinación, el set de datos puede variar, y en `Event`, tengo N cantidad de registros de Eventos (de los cuales algunos pueden estar como no en la tabla AppWindowEvent), en la tabla Event se identifica por idEntity.

Entonces, si para un `idAppWindow` y un `idMill`, quiero saber que Eventos tengo con valor (y los que no tienen valor) en la tabla `Event`, esto se resolvería de manera fácil con un `LEFT JOIN`, pero no consigo el resultado que deseo.

En el primer caso es como si hiciera un `INNER JOIN`, no devuelve valores NULLS, y en el segundo caso (cuando al `ON` del `JOIN` le agrego un filtro de `idEntity` funciona perfecto, devuelve la cantidad de Eventos que estan configurados para un `idMill` y `idAppWindow`, y los valores correspondidos en `Event`, los que no, es porque son registros nulos).

Cuando ejecuto este query:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
AppWindowsEvent AWE
LEFT JOIN Event E ON AWE.idEventType = E.idEventType
WHERE
AWE.idMill = 1
AND AWE.idAppWindow = 1
ORDER BY
AWE.[Order] ASC
```

El resultado no devuelve valores nulos.

Pero cuando ejecuto este otro query:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
AppWindowsEvent AWE
LEFT JOIN Event E ON AWE.idEventType = E.idEventType
AND E.[idEntity] = 1234
WHERE
AWE.idMill = 1
AND AWE.idAppWindow = 1
ORDER BY
AWE.[Order] ASC
```

El resultado devuelve registros nulos.

**NOTA:** si bien el segundo query anda, lo hace para un `idEntity` específico, en mi caso necesito todos los `idEntity`.

Comment: agrega a tu pregunta un pequeño conjunto de los datos que tienes en las tablas y un ejemplo del resultado que deseas obtener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la primera consulta que has escrito está correcta y cumple con lo que necesitas, lo que está mal es la segunda consulta que haces para comprobar los resultados.

El LEFT JOIN básicamente muestra todos los registros de la tabla de la izquierda y sus coincidencias con las tablas de la derecha, es decir que basta con que haya un registro que coincida ya no te mostrará nulos, usaré el siguiente ejemplo para explicarlo mejor en tu caso.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En las tablas [AppWindowsEvent] y [Event] tengo 2 registros en cada una, como ambos registros coinciden en el campo idEventType, el resultado es 2 registros sin nulos usando la consulta que publicaste.

Luego, al filtrar los registros de la tabla [Event] por el campo [idEntity] nos queda únicamente 1 registro, por lo tanto al realizar la consulta de comprobación que publicaste el motor no encuentra coincidencia para un registro de la tabla [AppWindowsEvent] y te muestra los campos como nulos.

Answer (score 1):

Estas haciendo un JOIN de dos tablas por un campo que no es primary key de la segunda tabla, lo que al final genera un resultado arbitrario.

Asumiendo que ese no sea el principal problema, tienes que evaluar cuál es la tabla que contiene la mayor cantidad de información. Esa sería la que debe ir primero en el JOIN.

```
SELECT
* FROM Event E 
LEFT JOIN AppWindowsEvent AWE 
ON AWE.idEventType = E.idEventType 
WHERE AWE.idMill = 1 AND AWE.idAppWindow = 1 
ORDER BY AWE.[Order] ASC
```

De esa manera obtendrias los NULLs que esperas.

Comment: para que sea mejor recibida la respuesta, pon un ejemplo con la consulta

Answer (score 0):

El `join` solo te buscará coincidencias exactas en este caso por ser `left` en la tabla, `Awe`, si quieres devolver todo aunque tenga nulos, debes utilizar un `union`

Comment: ¿Podrías especificar cómo esto respondería a la pregunta? Sería recomendable que incluyas el código que responde a la pregunta del autor.

Comment: Me parece que tu respuesta es de acuerdo al funcionamiento de un INNER JOIN y la pregunta del usuario es puntual acerca del uso de un LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Yo en un principio veo correcta la sentencia. Ya que de haber introducido en el WHERE una condición con un campo de la tabla Event en lugar LEFT pasaría a INNER, que no es el caso. ¿Podrías probar a quitar las claves ajenas de ambas tablas, ver como se comporta y nos comentas?

Comment: Podrías incluir un código que explique tu respuesta.

Comment: @Davlio Ilústrame y te pongo el ejemplo que quieras. No se qué código quieras que ponga de una pregunta